# Enable download of games

Tags: 8.0

Using Windows Phone 8 on a Nokia Lumia 920.
When I attempt to download a game, I get the error message:
"My Family settings for your account prevent you from downloading this item.  Your parent can manage My Family settings at windowsphone.com."
I am the parent!  How can I disable My Family, so I can download everything?
I've checked my date of birth for my Microsoft account and it has my correct date of birth.  (and I'm well over 18).

Comment: You'll probably have to call Microsoft support as it sounds like an issue with your account only they can solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xbox LIVE](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/online-privacy-and-safety/online-safety) determines whether an account is a child account or an adult account based on the age of the account owner. Account owners who are younger than 18 are given child accounts in the United States. The legal adult age varies by country and region.

Child accounts are tied to an adult's Microsoft account. The adult account can control Family Settings and restrict some features of Xbox LIVE.

To promote a child account to an adult account the adult account must:

- Sign in to Xbox LIVE by using the account that you want to change.
- Go to Settings, and then select Account.
- Select Promote Child Account.
- Follow the additional on-screen instructions to promote the account.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link. I am not sure whether this will work or not.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpapps/my-family-settings-are-preventing-me-from/dd95a0bf-24de-4711-85df-1ced03c2fc78

Especially this comment in the link.

`"I just got my windows phone, 4 days ago and I just figured it out how to fix it.. I made 2 parents account and make sure to check the terms and condition of microsoft and also make sure to log in to xbox.com and accept Xbox Terms of Service."`